# Where is mod_jk.dll in tomcat-connectors-1.2.42-src ?

Tags: apache, tomcat

I have downloaded the Tomcat Connector from http://tomcat.apache.org/download-connectors.cgi. The document said I should have the mod_jk.dll or mod_jk.so but I couldn't find it anywhere. I need it to install the Tomcat Connector said the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Tomcat community no longer produces mod_jk binaries for httpd for any OS. They are available from other sources such as [Apache Lounge](https://www.apachelounge.com/download/) but you can use mod_proxy_ajp instead for nearly all use cases.